Use a mapping function to map one property to another object
I have an array of objects as per below.
songs = [
  { 
    track_name: "name of track" , 
    track_genres: ["chamber pop","indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 2" , 
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b","indie soul", "indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 3" , 
    track_genres: ["indie pop","chamber pop","indie soul"] }
]

I have another mapping object that looks like this
genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{name:"chamber pop"},{name:"indie pop"}]
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{name:"dutch r&b"}]
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{name:"indie soul"}]
  }
]

What I want to do is for each track, go through the track genres, and use the "genres" variable to assign the parent genres for each track. Parent genre ideally shouldn't be repeated.
Expected Output:
const songs = [ 
{ 
  track_name: "name of track", 
  track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"], 
  parent_genres: ["Pop"] }, 
{ 
  track_name: "name of track 2", 
  track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"], 
  parent_genres: ["R&B","Soul","Pop"] }, 
{ 
  track_name: "name of track 3", 
  track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"], 
  parent_genres: ["Pop", "Soul"] }
];


use SET to handle duplicate parent genres

const getParentGenres = (trackGenres) => {
const parentGenres = new Set();
trackGenres.forEach(trackGenre => {
genres.forEach(genre => {
if (genre.children.some(child => child.name === trackGenre)) {
parentGenres.add(genre.name);
}
});
});
return Array.from(parentGenres);
};

this doesn't seem to be working. Can you add this as an answer please so it can run the snippet for expected output?

@NNS ... Regarding all the provided answers, are there any questions left?

I'd first transform your genres array into a Map which maps the children to the genre name:
{'chamber pop' => 'Pop', 'indie pop' => 'Pop', 'dutch r&b' => 'R&B', 'indie soul' => 'Soul'}

this can be done by flatMap-ing your genres array and then for each child object return a key-value pair that includes the genre-name as the value and the child name as the key:
new Map(genres.flatMap(genre => genre.children.map((child) => [child.name, genre.name])));

Once you have that map built, you can map through songs and add your parent_genres property and set it to an array. This array is a mapped version of your track_genres where you used the above Map to get the associated genre for each item. Then you can wrap this in a Set and spread the result back into array to remove any duplicates:


const genres = [ { name: "Pop", children: [{name:"chamber pop"},{name:"indie pop"}] }, { name: "R&B", children: [{name:"dutch r&b"}] }, { name: "Soul", children: [{name:"indie soul"}] } ];
const songs = [ { track_name: "name of track" , track_genres: ["chamber pop","indie pop"] }, { track_name: "name of track 2" , track_genres: ["dutch r&b","indie soul", "indie pop"] }, { track_name: "name of track 3" , track_genres: ["indie pop","chamber pop","indie soul"] } ];

const genreMap = new Map(genres.flatMap(genre => genre.children.map(child => [child.name, genre.name])));
const result = songs.map(song => ({
  ...song,
  parent_genres: [...new Set(song.track_genres.map(genre => genreMap.get(genre)))]
}));

console.log(result);




Quoting the OP ...

What I want to do is for each track, go through the track genres, and use the "genres" variable to assign the parent genres for each track.

Taking the two data-structures into account, the goal most easily can be achieved by looking up the main-genre by a sub-genre. This is where maps do shine, due to their efficiency in lookup-speed.
Thus one firstly needs to create such a Map based lookup-table by a flattening flatMap based transformation of the nested genres-specific data, where each genre-item's children-array is going to be mapped as e.g. subGenres in order to create lookup-entries for each found/existing sub-genre specific name.


const genres = [{
  name: "Pop",
  children: [{ name: "chamber pop" }, { name: "indie pop" }],
}, {
  name: "R&B",
  children: [{ name: "dutch r&b" }],
}, {
  name: "Soul",
  children: [{ name: "indie soul" }],
}];

const genreBySubGenreLookup = new Map(
  genres
    .flatMap(({ name: genreName, children: subGenres }) =>

      subGenres
        .map(({ name }) => [ name, genreName ])
    )
);

console.log(
  'genreBySubGenreLookup.get("chamber pop") ...',
  genreBySubGenreLookup.get("chamber pop"),
);
console.log(
  'genreBySubGenreLookup.get("indie pop") ...',
  genreBySubGenreLookup.get("indie pop"),
);
console.log(
  'genreBySubGenreLookup.get("dutch r&b") ...',
  genreBySubGenreLookup.get("dutch r&b"),
);
console.log(
  'genreBySubGenreLookup.get("indie soul") ...',
  genreBySubGenreLookup.get("indie soul"),
);
console.log({ lookup: Object.fromEntries(genreBySubGenreLookup) });
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }



Now one can focus on the OP's main task which is enhancing each item of the provided songs track-list.
Since the lookup-table is already in place, one might think that the remaining map-based (of cause) task can be implemented pretty straightforward, but the OP has a say again ...

Parent genre ideally shouldn't be repeated.

Even though the array of main-genre names can be created easily and fast due to the lookup, it most probably will feature multiple same values within the array. But creating a Set instance from an array assures unique set items (array items, once spread again) and spreading such a set creates/casts a new array.


const tracklist = songs
  .map(trackItem => {

    /*
      - the array of main-genre names, can be created easily
        and fast due to the lookup, but it most probably will
        feature multiple same values within the array.
      - creating a `Set` instance from an array assures unique
        set items (array items, once spread again).
      - spreading a `Set` instance creates/casts a new array.
    */
    const parent_genres = [...new Set(
      trackItem
        .track_genres
        .map(subGenre => genreBySubGenreLookup.get(subGenre))
    )];

    // returns a new track-item which gets created by ...
    return {

      // - spreading the current track-item into an (empty) object,
      ...trackItem,

      // - assigning the just created array of unique genre names.
      parent_genres,
    };
  });

console.log({ tracklist, songs });
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>

const songs = [{ 
  track_name: "name of track", 
  track_genres: ["chamber pop", "indie pop"],
}, { 
  track_name: "name of track 2", 
  track_genres: ["dutch r&b", "indie soul", "indie pop"],
}, { 
  track_name: "name of track 3", 
  track_genres: ["indie pop", "chamber pop", "indie soul"],
}];

const genres = [{
  name: "Pop",
  children: [{ name: "chamber pop" }, { name: "indie pop" }],
}, {
  name: "R&B",
  children: [{ name: "dutch r&b" }],
}, {
  name: "Soul",
  children: [{ name: "indie soul" }],
}];

const genreBySubGenreLookup = new Map(
  genres
    .flatMap(({ name: genreName, children: subGenres }) =>

      subGenres
        .map(({ name }) => [ name, genreName ])
    )
);
</script>




songs = [
  { 
    track_name: "name of track" , 
    track_genres: ["chamber pop","indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 2" , 
    track_genres: ["dutch r&b","indie soul", "indie pop"] },
  { 
    track_name: "name of track 3" , 
    track_genres: ["indie pop","chamber pop","indie soul"] }
]

genres = [
  {
    name: "Pop",
    children: [{name:"chamber pop"},{name:"indie pop"}]
  },
  {
    name: "R&B",
    children: [{name:"dutch r&b"}]
  },
  {
    name: "Soul",
    children: [{name:"indie soul"}]
  }
]

const getParentGenres = (trackGenres) => {
  const parentGenres = new Set(); 
  trackGenres.forEach(trackGenre => {
    genres.forEach(genre => {
      if (genre.children.some(child => child.name === trackGenre)) {
        parentGenres.add(genre.name); 
      }
    });
  });

  return Array.from(parentGenres); 
};


const updatedSongs = songs.map(song => ({
  ...song,
  parent_genres: getParentGenres(song.track_genres)
}));

console.log(updatedSongs);

